# IdentityServer3 MongoDb Admin Setup .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, identityserver3

I am using the MongoDb extension to IdentityServer3. 
There is an admin extension too at (https://github.com/jageall/IdentityServer.v3.Admin.MongoDb)

However, I am unsure how you initialise this and call its methods and set it up. IdentityServer3 is setup using AutoFac and I am not familiar on how this works and if the Admin extension is built using this.

I have created a MVC website that has a Insert page for the scopes but when I press insert button I am struggling on how I call the save method to save the scope using this extension.